# Sequences of refining partitions of a measurable space

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ be a measurable space. For $k\in\mathbb N$ let $(\mathcal F_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal F$ such that each $\mathcal F_k$ is generated by a finite partition $P_k$ of $\Omega$ and the partitions are refining, meaning that each element in $P_{k+1}$ is contained in an element of $P_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb N.$ Assume that to each $\mathcal F_k$ we have associated a probability measures $\mathbb Q_k$ such that $$E_{\mathbb Q_k}[X\mid\mathcal F_k]=0.$$ Do we have $$E_{\mathbb Q_m}[X\mid\mathcal F_k]=0$$ for each $m>k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional expectations with respect to a finite partition are functions that are almost surely constant on each cell of the partition and determined by the values on these partitions.

Now if $m>k$ and $Q_m$ is zero almost surely on each cell of a partition generating $\mathcal{F}_m$ then it is trivially zero almost surely on a finite union of such cells. And all cells of the partition generating $\mathcal{F}_k$ are of this form.